# end date greater than start date in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a php code as shown below:

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'D His', $data->{"select_start_day"} . ' '. $data->{"start_time"});   // Line A
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'D His', $data->{"select_end_day"} . ' '. $data->{"end_time"});         // Line B

print_r($startDate); echo "<br>"; // Line C
print_r($endDate); // Line D
```

**Line C and Line D print:**

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-10-05 14:34:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Toronto ) 
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2019-10-02 14:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/Toronto )
```

At Line A and Line B, the values inside `$data->{"select_start_day"}`, `$data->{"select_end_day"}`, `$data->{"start_time"}` and `$data->{"end_time"}` are entered by user.

For exampple, let us suppose the user has entered: 
**1.** `$data->{"select_start_day"}` = Saturday (sat) 
**2.** `$data->{"select_end_day"}` = Wednesday (wed) 
**3.** `$data->{"start_time"}` = 143400 
**4.** `$data->{"end_time"}` = 140000

**Problem Statement:**
I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that `$startDate` should always be less than `$endDate`.

In the o/p above `$startDate` is greater than `$endDate`. 
In the `$endDate`, `wednesday` should come after `saturday` so it should be `2019-10-09` rather than `2019-10-02`

Comment: What code gets written will depend on what you want to happen. Should the start date be changed? Should the end date be changed? If so, to what?

Comment: Maybe something like this? ```if ($start_date < $end_date) { $start_date = clone $end_date; $start_date->modify('-1 seconds'); }```

Comment: @JohnConde user only enter day of the week and time. Date gets automatically fetched. Is there any we can make end date greater than start date ?

Comment: This date `2019-10-05` is right for saturday but it is treating `2019-10-02` as wednesday. I want wednesday to be `2019-10-09`.

Comment: In short `Wednesday` should come after `Saturday`.